# I am getting error when trying to use addError() on Account Object

Tags: apex, trigger, lightning, adderror, development-mode

I tested this in my dev org for Account object:

### Class:

```
public class Account {
}
```

---

### Trigger:

```
trigger AccountTestTest on Account (before insert) {

   for(Account c: trigger.new){
        c.addError('asddbc');
   }
}
```

---

Method does not exist or incorrect signature: [Account].addError(String)

Comment: if we use Standard name prefixes we end up getting this mistake. Please avoid using standard name prefix as class name

Answer (score 2):

Your issue is that you created a class named `Account`. The compiler will look to that class over the SF Implementation of the standard Account class. Keep in mind all sObjects are instances of a Class themselves

Since you did that and did not define a method named `addError` it does not exist

```
public class Account {
}
```

**Strongly Suggest** you delete the `Account` class and you should be good to go

Comment: renaming the class will also help.

Comment: public class AccountAddition{}

Comment: @user39956 renaming the class effectively removes the 'Account' class. So yes that works to